# How view hmlTable in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-placeholder, htmltable-control

**Can I use HtmlTable class in asp.net MVC?**

I created HtmlTable object in Controller class:

```
 var Table1 = new HtmlTable();
```

**How to view it** in the web page?

When I use:
 
`PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(Table1);` in Controller class 

and

 `<asp:placeholder id="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:placeholder>` in index.cshtml  
I have warning "**Unrecognized namespace 'asp'**"
How bind `PlaceHolder1` from Controller class and `placeholder id="PlaceHolder1"` from View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the asp placeholder control with ASP.NET MVC. Almost all controls require view state, which ASP.NET MVC doesn't support.

Comment: msdn: "The HtmlHelper class is designed to generate UI. It should not be used in controllers or models."
But I need something for work in Controller.

Comment: What do you want the placeholder for? Do you need to set the tables visibility or some other properties based on some property in the controller?

Comment: I need create dynamic table. All information about raws and columns are in lists of objects. I used:
 for example  `@Html.Raw(ViewBag.htmlFirstColumn)`

Comment: This is best dealt with in the View and not the Controller. I guess you are passing a collection of items in your model to render in the table. You can construct your table in the View by using razor syntax or by using a HtmlHelper, passing in the parameters you need to the Helper method call.